# reorder array-table row and update database

Tags: database, arrays, sql-update, sorting

I've been looking for a way to do something and I'm convinced I've been using the wrong search criteria to finding a solution...so, here I am.

I have a dropdown menu in a content management system that when a new page is created or position is edited, the database is updated with the new or edited value...this is all working great.

However, what I'd like to do is...when a number for the page position is changed from let's say, position 5 to position 1...the former position number 1 is changed to position number 2...and every position number for any pages remaining are renumbered accordingly.

So, my question is, how do I UPDATE my database so, whenever I change the position of the page in the dropdown menu, ALL position values get, I don't know, a +1...or something...and additionally, NOT allowing two position values to be the same...you know, there can be only one...

Thanks in advance...hope I didn't do too bad in explaining what I'd like to do :-)

Comment: Could you post what you've attempted thus far?

Comment: So far jrd1, I've only been looking for a way to do it...I haven't actually tried anything yet...I just can't seem to get what I'm trying to do in the proper search criteria...it just seems like what I want to do is so simple...but as I'm learning with PHP, simple is rarely the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
UPDATE my_table SET position=position+1 WHERE position>2 AND position<5
```

The where statement should be the new position & old position of the one you've just updated

Comment: ...thanks, but my UPDATE is not just the position...here is partial code that shows the update for my pages...

`if (empty($errors)) {
 $query = "UPDATE pages SET
  menu_name = '{$menu_name}',
  position = {$position},
  visible = {$visible},
  content = '{$content}',
  pg_desc = '{$pg_desc}',
  pg_keywords = '{$pg_keywords}'
 WHERE id = {$id}";
$result = mysql_query($query);`